# Python: Print Text Of Element Each Second For A Certain Amount Of Time

Tags: python, python-3.x, appium, pytest

I have problems with printing each second an element that is refreshed in the application (android appium).

I have an app that generates a text each second and I need to print that information for 60 seconds.

I have tried using the WebDriver Wait I tried as well the time.sleep, even the threading.Timer but that one requires a function call and since I am beginner I have a problem with nested functions for pytest

Using timer:

```py
def testSignal(i):
         dbm = self.driver.find_element_by_id("com.ubnt.usurvey:id/vSignal")
         print(dbm.text)
         sys.stdout.write(str(i) + '\r')
         sys.stdout.flush()
         i += 1
         threading.Timer(1, testSignal, [i]).start()
```

Using WebDriverWait:

```py
wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 60, poll_frequency=1)
dbm = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID,"com.ubnt.usurvey:id/vSignal")))
text = dbm.text
print(text)
```

Using time.sleep:

```py
dbm = self.driver.find_element_by_id("com.ubnt.usurvey:id/vSignal")
text = dbm.text
print(text)
time.sleep(60)
```

I am new with this and I have problems on looping the print based on searching an element (After reload).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not understand your code but i think this will work.

```py
dbm = self.driver.find_element_by_id("com.ubnt.usurvey:id/vSignal")
while True:
    text = None
    try:
        text = dbm.text
    except:
        pass
    if not text:
        break
    print(text)
    time.sleep(1)
```

If you want to stop it by CTRL + C (KeyboardInterrupt) and don't want to stop or crash the code, you can add another `try`:

```py
dbm = self.driver.find_element_by_id("com.ubnt.usurvey:id/vSignal")
try:
    while True:
        text = None
        try:
            text = dbm.text
        except:
            pass
        if not text:
            break
        print(text)
        time.sleep(1)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Loop stopped in a controlled manner.")
```

Comment: Sorry about my code, yes I messed it up! 
Thank you so much about the code, looks super good, unfortunately for me it prints only once at the end of the 60 second :(

Comment: However if I add time.sleep(1) will print more time the correct value BUT only after I stop it, I cannot make it stop without stoping manually the test

Comment: ```time.sleep(sec)``` is a function that waits "sec" seconds. Example if you want to wait like ```delay(microseconds)``` in Arduino you can use decimal numbers like "0.060".

Comment: Be cautious to apply this code to longer time intervals, because then the time to execute the other lines in the loop will pile up. Based on the code https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/python/python+loop+to+do+something+every+1+second , you should use time.sleep(1 - time.time() % 1 ) instead.